# Animation in vb with wpf

Tags: android, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I am working on vb project in visual studio 2015.I need to animate the text **"Darkode"** from left to right.

I tried the following code which i pulled from the internet,

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left" From="1920" To="0" AccelerationRatio=".1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

But i didn't understand it Correctly? I need more clarification on the topic.

Comment: Interesting combination of tags but if there is any vb.net involved take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700597/smoothly-scroll-text-like-breaking-news)

Comment: Thanks for the help .I compiled his code but the output is not what i have in my mind .Any way thanks. I choose the keywords specifically for a reason. I included android because android uses xml for designing the ui where as wpf uses xml also for its ui.visual studio 2012,2015 doesn't matter because i am not using any code that is version dependent.visual c++ i choose because i know little c++.i am new to visual basic so if any know how to solve my problem i am open to all suggeation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had encountered a similar situation where i had to Animate my logo. After searching for hours in the internet i found a solution which was not very useful to me but given your situation **(animate a text from left to right)** ,it will be more useful to you.

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub trmText_Timer()
   If lblCaption.Caption <> StrCap Then
        lblCaption.Caption = Left(StrCap, Len(lblCaption.Caption) + 1)
   Else
      lblCaption.Caption = ""
   End If
End Sub
```

Here is the source for the code:http://www.setha.info/ict-visualbasic6/72-ict-vb6-0013.html

Here is the link for my qusetion :[Animation of words in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748660/animation-of-words-in-visual-studio?noredirect=1#comment70689957_41748660)

**Explanation**
Unlike the code you posted in your question which uses storyboard for animation the above code uses Timer control for animation.

> In the above code **StrCap** contains your text **darkode** and
>   **lblCaption.Caption** is an empty string onto which you iterativly put you text charater by charater on each iteration.

Heres a link if you want to know more about timer control :[Timer Control](http://vb.net-informations.com/gui/timer-vb.htm)

Comment: Thank you @Aravind TA for your help. I will try your code and update soon

Comment: Thank you @ControlFreak happy to help.